# Best Swift/iOS practice for changing speed/movement of objects based on device or screen size?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

My question would be best asked with a simple example:

If I have a game where a ball is near the bottom of the screen, and the goal of the game is to dodge objects scrolling down towards it, I am having trouble figuring out the best method to make the game "fair."

If the game screen is larger, then that player has an advantage because they see the scrolling objects at the top of the screen with more time to move away from it.

I'm wondering...what is the best practice to "scale" the game to where regardless of the size of the screen, the rate at which the scrolling objects move towards the ball, and eventually reach it is exactly the same?

My first instinct is to scale how fast the objects scroll with the size of the frame the game is in.  But for some reason that feels clunky to me, or that if I just scale all the objects relative to the size of the screen, that is enough and I'm worrying over something minimal at best.

Anybody ever had a same kind of issue?  What is the best means to have a things "behave" the same if the size of the screen/frame plays a key role in your game?

I am open to general Swift and SpriteKit, as I am just in early stages of thinking how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

For SpriteKit, you'll normally design the game, including the sizes and speeds of objects, with some particular logical frame size.  That will then get scaled to fill the screen in some appropriate way.  How the scaling should be done depends on the game though.  Usually you don't want to have different scalings for width and height, so the issue boils down to how to handle different aspect ratios.  There are two main possibilities:

1. Make sure there's a certain minimum amount of the game area shown, and show a bit more either horizontally or vertically depending on aspect ratio.  Potentially unfair if you don't do anything else, but as you mentioned something like scaling object speeds can compensate.
2. Pad out the game area with some non-playing area parts (perhaps decorative, or containing parts of the controls, score display, etc.)  Depending on device aspect ratio, different parts of this get cut off or shown.  The real playing area is exactly the same dimensions on all devices.

Comment: Ideally I would like just the game to be full screen, regardless of device, so an iPhone sized screen on a large iPad would look strange.  Seems 1 might be my best bet, have the minimum height or width covered by a background, and if it exceeds the frame so be it, then adjust sizes/speeds of sprites accordingly.  I had an idea of what to do, but I just wasn't sure the ideal way of doing so.  Appreciate the answer and I will try out your advice!

Comment: When I say a logical frame size, I mean you design the game for a 100x100 coordinate system or 2000x1000 or whatever makes sense.  That will be scaled to the real device as appropriate, cutting off parts or letterboxing or whatever, but regardless it's going to fill the screen to the degree possible, i.e., the iPad display will never just show a little iPhone-sized bit in the middle.  Anyway, good luck.